# Which performs better - using grep vs for loop in perl?

Tags: arrays, performance, perl

Let's say If user wants to filter elements from an array based on a certain condition. User has two choices. Either he can use one line `grep` statement or write a for loop and store elements based on certain condition.

For e.g.

`my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);`

Option 1 : `my @filtered = grep { $_/2 eq 0 } @array;`

Option 2 :

```
foreach (@array) 
{ 
  if($_/2 eq 0) { 
    push @filtered, $_;
  } 
}
```

Which is preferred way of writing if performance is a factor?

Comment: Always profile before optimization. http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first option has to be faster in general since `grep` has specific optimizations.

However, that statement is far too general and you need to benchmark it, in particular under conditions that apply to your work.

An example using [Benchmark](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Getopt::Long;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $time = 3;
my $size = 10_000;

GetOptions( 'time=i' => \$time, 'size=i' => \$size )  or usage();

sub w_grep {
    my @res = grep { $_/2 > $size/4 } @{$_[0]};
    return \@res;
}

sub w_for {
    my @res;
    for (@{$_[0]}) { 
        push @res, $_ if $_/2 > $size/4; 
    }   
    return \@res;
}

my @t = 1..$size;

cmpthese( -$time, {
    grep => sub { w_grep(\@t) },
    for  => sub { w_for(\@t) },
});

sub usage {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 [--time NUM] [--size NUM]";
    exit;
}
```

The condition is true about half of the time so a scalar gets created and added that often.  Creating a lot of scalars is expensive and this is likely the main factor, how often your condition is true.

It prints (on a desktop with v5.16 under CentOS 7)

```
       Rate  for grep
for   948/s   -- -13%
grep 1085/s  14%   --
```

However, if we make the condition more restrictive, say `$_/2 > $size/2`, then we get

```
       Rate  for grep
for  1217/s   --  -6%
grep 1296/s   6%   --
```

while when it succeeds most of the time, for say `$_/2 > 10`, the rates are

```
       Rate  for grep
for   945/s   -- -28%
grep 1304/s  38%   --
```

This shows that `for` falls further behind as there is more additions to the array.

But please remember that this depends in many other ways on what choices you make for tests, some rather subtle and some not so subtle.

For example, unpacking the arrayref first (`my @ary = @{ $_[0] };`) reduces the difference to a mere few percent, since the runtime is dominated by creating a local array.  That would throw your tests -- or perhaps reflect your situation.  You need to make careful choices for your conditions.

The numbers of course also vary with array sizes, complexity of the calculation, etc.

Comment: Yep. Quite right - the answer is benchmark it if you care. Of course, I'd still go with not worrying about it overall - they both have to iterate the whole array, and so are both O(N) functions. If you could bail out of the `for` on an early result, then it would steal a hefty lead.

Comment: @Sobrique My sentiment exactly.  Plus `grep` is the tool for the job, that is what it's for.  But since the question is very clearly about performance aspects I restrained from making other comments ... but I may also add a small general comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @toolic commented, see [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). I changed your condition slightly so that the output array is actually populated with something:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

for my $arraylen (10, 100, 10_000) {
    print "#### arraylen $arraylen ###\n";
    my @array = 1..$arraylen;
    cmpthese( -1, {
        grep => sub {
            my @filtered = grep { $_%2 } @array;
        },
        loop => sub {
            my @filtered;
            foreach (@array) { 
                if ($_%2) { 
                    push @filtered, $_;
                } 
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Output:

```
#### arraylen 10 ###
          Rate loop grep
loop 1514033/s   -- -10%
grep 1683494/s  11%   --
#### arraylen 100 ###
         Rate loop grep
loop 176987/s   -- -16%
grep 210436/s  19%   --
#### arraylen 10000 ###
       Rate loop grep
loop 1794/s   -- -18%
grep 2201/s  23%   --
```

So it appears that, at least on my machine with my Perl, `grep` is faster. However, as always with optimizations, you might want to consider whether this performance impact is significant in the context of your larger program, since for example trying to stuff a complicated condition into a `grep` can make your code less readable. And you should benchmark the code you are actually running instead of taking "`grep` is always faster than `foreach`+`push`" as a general rule!

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is slightly faster on my machine...

```
my @array;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++ ) {
  push @array, $i;
}


my $start = time;
my @filtered = grep { $_/2 eq 0 } @array;
my $duration = time - $start;
print "Execution time: $duration s\n";

my $start = time;
foreach (@array) 
{ 
  if($_/2 eq 0) {
    push @filtered, $_;
  } 
}
my $duration = time - $start;
print "Execution time: $duration s\n";
```

Output:

```
Execution time: 296 s
Execution time: 233 s
```

Comment: It's kind of weird to compare numeric values with the string comparison operator `eq` rather than the numeric comparison operator `==`.

Comment: @Grant McLean Good point, although I used the code in the initial question. Using `==` makes things much faster (as one could expect) , with advantage to option 1 this time:'
`Execution time: 63 s
Execution time: 80 s`