# Exclude a string using grep -v

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a requirement to exclude a selected string. I am trying to use `grep -v` option.

Input:

```
AM2RGHK
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

Output should be:

```
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

From the input list, If I want to exclude only first line, I am using `grep -v AM2RGHK`
But I am not getting any output. `grep -v` excludes all the strings in the same sequence. Any clue?

Comment: Why do you only want the first line removed? Do you want an exact match (full line). or only delete at most one line or some other requirement?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is matching all the input lines because it's default behavior is to match line that *contains* the given pattern. It doesn't have to be exactly equal to it.

You can tell grep that it has to find an exact match by using the option `-x` (`--line-regexp`).

`grep -v -x AM2RGHK` does what you want.

---

Side notes:

Since you don't seem to use an actual regex but you just need simple text match, you may consider the option `-F` (`--fixed-strings`). It tells `grep` to not give special meaning to any character in the pattern.

Moreover, it's always a good practice to encase shell strings in `''`. This ensures that the shell doesn't try to interpret any characters, like whitespaces. It can spare you a lot of headaches.

The resulting command would be:

```
grep -vxF 'AM2RGHK'
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
grep -v '^AM2RGHK$' input.txt
```

input.txt:

```
AM2RGHK
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

standard output:

```
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

Comment: This is missing an explanation. `^` means the line has to start here and there cannot be any characters before. `$` is an analogous for the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks @NO_NAME for additional explanation. @parmswrn also run`man re_format` for more information.

Comment: should explain that it's regex.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you have control over, in this case you can compare against the string in question but instead of just the string we can add a pad character on each end and look for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
read_file="/tmp/list.txt"
exclude="AM2RGHK"
while IFS= read -r line ;do
   if ! [[ "Z${line}Z" = "Z${exclude}Z" ]] ;then
      echo "$line"
   fi
done < "${read_file}"
```

This case we are saying if ZAM2RGHKZ != current then print it, the comparison would be as follows:

```
ZAM2RGHKZ  = ZAM2RGHKZ  do nothing
ZAM2RGHKZ != ZAM2RGHK-JOZ print because they don't match
ZAM2RGHKZ != ZAM2RGHK-FNZ print because they don't match
```

Hence the output becomes:

```
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

Note: there are more succinct ways to do this but this is a good way as well.

Comment: That's a nice solution if you hate `grep` but you like verbose and sluggish bash scripts.

Comment: @NO_NAME . You are comlpletely wrong. 'grep' is less readbale code and actually slower in many cases (benchmark tests). Plus grep isn't logic, teaching someone to actually code is also better. Moreover, it is how this code is used in a wider context of a script which makes the largest impact.  The above is O(n), that is fine.

Comment: Is that irony? `grep` is highly optimized, compiled, specialized program to do exactly what OP wants. There is no way it can beat an interpreted script. Especially bash which is so slow, it beats even Python. I guess teaching someone to code is fine but it is different than giving someone, who asked specifically about `grep`, 8 lines of code snippet without any explanation of how it works ;-P

Comment: This is an idiotic conversation ..  anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656916/which-performs-better-using-grep-vs-for-loop-in-perl

Comment: I don't think perl benchmarks apply to bash. I can't say more about it because I don't know perl.

Answer (score 0):

grep has the option -x

> ```
>    -x, --line-regexp
>           Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

for example:

```
[dachnik@test]$ cat > greptest
AM2RGHK
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN[dachnik@test]$ cat greptest
AM2RGHK
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN[dachnik@test]$ grep -v -x AM2RGHK greptest
AM2RGHK-JO
AM2RGHK-FN
```

Comment: Interesting idea.